# How can i re run user data on aws ec2 from the console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data, cloud-init

I would like to ask if there is a way to re-execute user data on a launched instance.
I want to restart a service and to edit ~./ssh/autorized_keys.

I found information at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/
but the cloud log from the console does not show anything to have changed.

Answer (score 1):

AWS only run the user data at the first launch. You need do the following two things:

1. use mime-multipart to append your new scripts. You could the command `write-mime-multipart` in `cloud-utils` to create the mime-multipart file. Please refer the [Cloud-init](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html) if you need more details.
2. use mime-multipart to set `scripts-user` run `always`. In `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`, refer [Always run cloud-init scripts](https://github.com/gbraad/knowledge-base/blob/master/technology/cloudinit.md) to see the options

So, you need copy all the scripts from the link your provided and replace the shell script part with yours. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============5940869395195845375=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============5940869395195845375==
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--===============5940869395195845375==
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
/bin/echo "Hello World." >> /tmp/abcde
--===============5940869395195845375==
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this using an SSH session. Took a copy of the user data as a script and reran it from the CL.

```
curl http://instance-data/latest/user-data > user-data.sh
chmod u+x user-data.sh
sudo ./user-data.sh
```

***Just be sure that when you rerun the user-data.sh script that you edit out any commands you might not want to rerun.***

Comment: Since posting this answer I've returned to the issue and found this https://serverfault.com/questions/797482/how-to-make-ec2-user-data-script-run-again-on-startup